# Может ли NGINX работать с несколькими директориями для статических файлов?

Tags: nginx

Есть две директории `/test/app/dist/images` и `/test/vendor/static`.
В обеих могут лежать статические файлы. Если в URL картинки содержится сегмент `/static`, то nginx должен искать такую картинку в директории `/test/vendor/static`, а если URL просто заканчивается на `.jpg, .png` и проч то nginx такой файл должен искать в директории `/test/app/dist/images`.
Я написал такой конфиг:

```
server {
  listen *:12901;
  server_name test.lan; 

  location / { 
    proxy_pass http://lan_nodes;
    //....
  }


  location ~* /static/*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt|ejs|json) {
    root /test/app/dist/images;
    expires 10d;
  }


  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt|ejs|json)$ {
    root /test/vendor/static;
    expires 10d;
  }

}
```

Но при попытке обратиться по адресу `test.lan/static/img/test/43a398b30dd39fc56ce97898758b4776.png` получаю 404 ошибку. Подскажите как правильно настроить nginx для такого случая?

Comment: `*` в регулярных выражениях означает 0 и более символов, которые стоят прямо перед ней. Так что `/*` означает 0 или более косых. т.е. ваше выражение сработает только на `static///.jpg` для имени файла там нет места. любое кол-во любых символов это `.*`

Comment: Rewrite надо использовать в регексп локациях, переписывайте путь для каждой локации.

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас в конфиге написано ровно обратное сформулированному: при наличии /static/ ищет в images и наоборот.

Comment: @Mike Можете дать развернутый ответ с примером? Я сделал так `location ~ ^/static/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt|ejs|json)$ { root /node_data/qa/drrf/static; }` и это тоже не работает....

Comment: посмотрите логи, там должно быть видно куда он реально пытался обратится